# How can I pipe the output of the serial port to a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port

How can I pipe the output of the serial port to a file in Windows?

In Linux the command would be:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > /opt/logs/Serial.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess:

```
copy com1: somefile.log
```

There is also `con:` and `nul:` special device as I remember. But that was true for times when DOS was more popular. Probably now you have to create some strange file/folder with extension where in curly brakets is placed some scary long sequence of numbers and letters :)

Comment: It works, I've tried just today

Answer (score 1):

I find more usefull this one:

```
type com1: >> data.log
```

The main advantages versus a `copy` is that you can append data to an existing file and you can open the file with another application (notepad) to see the contents.